# Google Cloud Datastore get an object from array

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

How can I retrieve an object by id from an array property using NodeJs Datastore SDK?

I have a Kind named Team with a property Players. I need to get a player by id.

Here's an example of team entity:

```
{
    "id" : "T01",
    "name" : "My Team",
    "city" : "London",
    "players" : [
        {
            "id" : "P01",
            "name" : "John",
            "lastName" : "Doo",
            "height" : "181"
        },
        {
            "id" : "P02",
            "name" : "Mario",
            "lastName" : "Rossi",
            "height" : "185"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `team.players.find(item => item.id == id)` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

An example like this might be helpful using the SDK.

https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/blob/master/samples/tasks.list.js

It uses the query:

```
  const query = datastore.createQuery('Task').order('created');
```

So in theory you could do this:

```
  const query = datastore.createQuery('Team').filter('player.id', '=', playerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to query for all Teams and then search through each Team’s **players** property with a **for loop**. The example below declares `queryResult` and sets its value as an array of Player objects that match the desired ID:

```
  const query = datastore.createQuery('Team');
  const desiredId = "P01";

  const queryResult = await datastore.runQuery(query).then(results => {
     const teams = results[0];
     let players = [];
     teams.forEach(team => {
         // Below we search for a valid player with the desired ID
         const matchedPlayer = team.players.find(player => player.id == desiredId);
         // If we find a valid player we "push it" to the players array.
         if(matchedPlayer) {
             players.push(matchedPlayer);
         }
     });
     return players;
  });
```

Comment: Yes, it works but I'm looking for a way to do that with Datastore queries.

Comment: If you are going to work a lot with queries for individual players, I suggest you create a new entity kind for Players and add the Team ID as a property. Otherwise, since you are querying for “Teams“, you will always get the whole team entity as a result. I actually tested the solution offered by @sterowney and it worked for me when I filtered for `players.id` instead of `player.id`, but again it returned the whole team and I still needed to iterate through every player to get only the ones I wanted.